# find command with exec in python subprocess gives error

Tags: python, find, subprocess

I'm trying to execute the following command using subprocess module (python)

```
/usr/bin/find <filepath> -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "<pattern>" -exec basename {} \;
```

But, it gives the following error :

```
/usr/bin/find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

I am guessing it's to do with escaping some characters. But not getting how to get over this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the line of code where you launch the subprocess

Answer (score 15):

An answer on another question helped:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15035344/971529

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(('find', '/tmp/mount', '-type', 'f',
              '-name', '*.rpmsave', '-exec', 'rm', '-f', '{}', ';'))
```

The thing I couldn't figure out was that the semi-colon didn't need to be escaped, since normally the semi-colon is interpreted by bash, and needs to be escaped.

In bash this equivelent is:

```
find /tmp/mount -type f -name "*.rpmsave" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

One more hint: Using the syntax r'bla' allows using backslashs without having to quote them:

```
r'... -exec basename {} \;'
```

Provides better readability.

Answer (score -2):

remember escaping `"` is required and also escaping `\` used before `;` is also required

your command might look something like:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/find", "<filepath> -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname \"<pattern>\" -exec basename {} \\;"])
p1.communicate()
```

Comment: If the OP is using single quotes (`'`) for the string, there is no need to escape the double quotes.

Comment: Thanks. Single quotes around the whole command string worked.

Comment: Even though you succeeded, could you provide the original code @shruthi? And how you fixed it?

Comment: Also note: This doesn't really work. It will interpret the whole second arguement (from <filepath> to \\;) as the path, which is not what you expect, or want.