# How to copy files using subprocess in python?

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

I have a list of files:

```
file_list=['test1.txt','test2.txt','test3.txt']
```

I want to find and copy these files to a destination folder. I have the following code:

```
for files in file_list:
    subprocess.call(["find", "test_folder/",
                    "-iname", files,
                    "-exec", "cp", "{}",
                    "dest_folder/",
                    "\;"])
```

But, i keep getting the error:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec
```

The shell command looks something like this:

$find test_folder/ -iname 'test1.txt' -exec cp {} dest_folder/ \;

Anything i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to escape semi-colon. Here's what is working for me:

```
import shlex
import subprocess

file_list = ['test1.txt','test2.txt','test3.txt']

cmd = 'find test_folder -iname %s -exec cp {} dest_folder ;'
for files in file_list:
    subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd % files))
```

Also see:

- [Python equivilant to find -exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035253/python-equivilant-to-find-exec/15035344#15035344)
- [find command with exec in python subprocess gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799594/find-command-with-exec-in-python-subprocess-gives-error)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I dont get any error now, but the destination folder doesnt have the copied files. Is there a way to look at whats being run? :)

Comment: I dont get any error now, but the destination folder doesnt have the copied files. Is there a way to print the subprocess being run? :)

Comment: @msakya hm, it's working for me. You may find the way to log the commands here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836947/output-the-command-line-called-by-subprocess

Comment: @msakya does adding `shell=True` argument to `Popen` make any difference?

Comment: This is weird, I am not really sure whats going on. putting `shell=True` didnt help.

Comment: @msakya by the way, I've modified the code a bit (using `shlex` now).

Comment: I rewrote the function as per your rewrite, `def findcopy(full_path, list_of_files, dest_folder):
    """
    """
    import subprocess
    import shlex

    cmd = 'find %s -iname %s -exec cp {} %s ;'
    for gen_files in list_of_files:
        subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd % (full_path, gen_files, dest_folder)))` but it still gives me no copied files. Does it have to do with supplying `dest_folder` as a variable too.

Comment: @msakya nope. Are you sure you have these `txt` files inside `test_folder`?

Comment: yes they are. I just ran `find` independently from shell and it works.

Comment: I apologize. I found the bug in the code. Your first answer worked all along. Again, sorry.

Comment: you should call `shlex.quote(filename)`, to support filename with spaces

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape the arguments; `subprocess` module calls `find` command directly without the shell. Replace `"\;"` with `";"` and your command will work as is.

You could combine the search into a single command:

```
from subprocess import call

expr = [a for file in file_list for a in ['-iname', file, '-o']]
expr.pop() # remove last `-o`
rc = call(["find", "test_folder/", "("] + expr + [")", "-exec", 
           "cp", "-t", "dest_folder/", "--", "{}", "+"])
```

You could also combine `expr` list into a single `-iregex` argument if desired.

You don't need `find` command; you could implement the copying in pure Python using `os.walk`, `re.match`, and `shutil.copy`:

```
import os
import re
import shutil

found = re.compile('(?i)^(?:%s)$' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, file_list))).match
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('test_folder/'):
    for filename in files:
        if found(filename):
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, filename), "dest_folder/")
```

Comment: yeah you are right on the first one, I got it to working after an inherent bug not related to the code. Is latter option any better than former? Thanks!

Comment: @msakya: the single `find` command should be faster: it copies several files at a time. The pure Python solution should be more portable (it doesn't require `find`, `cp` commands).