# Using regular expression in subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to automate a particular process using subprocess module in python. For example, if I have a set of files that start with a word plot and then 8 digits of numbers. I want to copy them using the subprocess run command.

```
copyfiles = subprocess.run(['cp', '-r', 'plot*', 'dest'])
```

When I run the code, the above code returns an error "**cp: plot*: No such file or directory**"

How can I execute such commands using subprocess module? If I give a full filename, the above code works without any errors.

Comment: I'd create a list of candidates first using `os.listdir()` and filter this list using regex. The pass the matching elements to your subprocess in a loop.

Comment: Wildcards are processed by the shell, *not* by individual utilities such as `cp`.  But the default behavior for `subprocess` is to not involve a shell at all - you'd need to add `shell=True` to get this to work (in which case you should supply the command as a single string, rather than a list of individual parameters).

Comment: @jasonharper please make an answer out of this comment. You are exactly right

Comment: @white I did this, and it works for me. Thanks for the quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a useful but probably not the best efficent `code` fragment from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572528/how-to-copy-files-using-subprocess-in-python), where an additional `python` library is used ([shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html)), and what I propose is to use `os.listdir` method to iterate over folder that you need to copy files, save in a list `file_list` and filter using a `lambda` function to extract specific file names, define a **command** sentence as **string** and use [`subproccess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) to execute the child process to copy the files on to a destination folder.

```py
import shlex
import os
import subprocess

# chage directory where your files are located at
os.chdir('C:/example_folder/')

# you can use os.getcwd function to check the current working directory
print(os.getcwd)
 
# extract file names
file_list = os.listdir() 
file_list = list(filter(lambda file_name: file_name.startswith('plot'), file_list))

# command sentence
cmd = 'find test_folder -iname %s -exec cp {} dest_folder ;'

for file in file_list:
    subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd % file))
```

Comment: Thanks for resolving the issue. I just made a list of filenames and used a loop to copy the files to the destination folder.